# angularJs factory with objects, returning undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create constant factory. but this returns undefined in controller.
Angular1.7 and es6 in use

```
export default getConstantsFactory;

    function getConstantsFactory(){

            function getConstants() {
            let constants = {};

            constants = {
                events = {

                },
                texts = {
                    MY_CONSTANT :'my constant'
                },
                numbers = {

                }
            };

            return constants;
        }

        return {getConstants:getConstants};
    }
```

---

Injected the same factory to controller

```
myController.$inject = ['getConstantsFactory'];

 function myController(getConstantsFactory){
     console.log(getConstantsFactory.getConstants()); // this returns undefined
 }
 export default myController;
```

---

defined controller and factory

```
import homeController from './home/home.controller.js';
import constantsFactory from './home/constantsFactory.js';

    export default angular.module('home', ['ngRoute'])
          .controller('homeController', homeController)
          .factory('constantsFactory', constantsFactory)
```

Please ignore syntax errors ,typo errors or any config errors.
Every thing is up and running expect I am not getting desire results from factory -- this should return objects but I am getting undefined.

Comment: Can you show how you imported `getConstantsFactory` to register it with Angular?

Comment: added the same in question. Thanks

Comment: There was something wrong in Json structure, fixed that and problem got resolved . Thank you